# Highmaps: Need to get unplotted data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I want to get the data points which cannot be plotted on the underlying map (i.e. joinBy fails to map the data to the geojson). Is there any way to get the unplotted data?

Comment: Do you have live demo (jsFiddle) with that case? In general, there isn't method like `getUnplottedData` ;) However, we should be able to check if `point.graphic` exists to determine if point is rendered or not.

Comment: @PawełFus [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrg93/spmx9xu3) There is a data point "none" which is not plotted since its not a valid country name. Is there any way I can get this unplotted data point (or a list of unplotted data points) programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check all points and find which are not plotted, the condition is that point has a `value` but doesn't have `graphic`:

```
chart: {
    events: {
    load: function () {
        var chart = this,
            unplottedPoints = [];

      $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, point) {
         if (point.value && !point.graphic) {
            unplottedPoints.push(point);
         }
      });

      console.log(unplottedPoints);
    }
  }
},
```

In array `unplottedPoints` you have list of all not rendered points.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/spmx9xu3/1/